# How this parameter knows the argument

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

Im confused with how the elem get the value of arr?

```js
function lengGreaterThan(num) {
  function lengGreaterThanNum(elem) {
      return elem.length > num;
  }
  return lengGreaterThanNum;
}

let arr = ['Justin', 'caterpillar', 'openhome'];
console.log(arr.filter(lengGreaterThan(6)));
```

Comment: `lengGreaterThan(6)` evaluates to `function lengGreaterThanNum(elem) { return elem.length > 6; }`. This function is passed to `.filter()`, which calls it once for each element of the array, passing that element as first argument. Writing a function that is called by the API rather than yourself takes some wrapping your head around it, but it'll click eventually ;)

Comment: Read about closures, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), [here](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_hOd+yVxaku); ...

Answer (score 1):

That is a really confusing way of writing it, but essentially you are just putting a function that takes one parameter into the filter function.

This here would do the same thing:

```
console.log(arr.filter((elem) => {
    return elem.length > 6;
}));
```

Comment: Actually it's not the same, OP's code takes the advantage of the closure, and they can reuse the same function to filter based on the different length, whereas you've hardcoded the length to compare.

Comment: Thats not what I meant, the code example is just there to explain to what it evaluates in the end for this specific example. The 6 could still be a variable or something. @Teemu

Comment: @Teemu OP's code uses two separate concepts, a) closures b) writing functions that are called by API methods. As I read the question, OP mainly struggles with b), not so much a), but I could be wrong